# I can't correctly check the response status from URLSession in func. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, session, url, completionhandler

function return result nil. I know it works async. I try with completionHandler but I can't do it good enough and I've got many errors only. How to use completionHandler in this case? Is there an easier way to check the token?

```
func isAuthenticated() -> Bool {
        guard let url = URL(string: self.url + "/api/authenticate") else {
            return false
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue(JWT.getToken(), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        var result: Bool?
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else { print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                result = true
            } else {
                result = false
            }
        }.resume()
        return result!
    }
```

function call:

```
    if isAuthenticated() {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginOK", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: `dataTask(with:completion:)` is asynchrone. You can't return it as such, because the completion hasn't been done yet. When you do `if httpResponse.statusCode == 200`, add just before `print("Did get httpResponse: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")`, and just before `return result!` add ``print("before return")`. Which one will be printed first? In your opinion? In reality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func isAuthenticated(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: self.url + "/api/authenticate") else {
        completion(false)
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue(JWT.getToken(), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else { print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

function call:

```
isAuthenticated() { success in
    if success {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginOK", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code with some changes and it work :) 
apiManager is class object with func 'isAuthenticated' 
apiManager.isAuthenticated { (success) in
                if success {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginOK", sender: self)
                    }

                }
            }

Comment: Hi, im trying to make a func out of it with another overridden code. static func getHttpRequest(_ urlLink: String, _ headers: Dictionary<String, String>?, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) { }. How to make an overridden func like static func getHttpRequest(_ url: String, completion: @ escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) { } what is inside is getHttpRequest(url, nil) but gives out an error